# Unable to assign user to a model object which changed the model object

Tags: django, python-3.x, inheritance, django-models, django-simple-history

I am using `django-simple-history` to maintain history of my model changes.

I am trying to associate user changing the service object using the way proposed [here](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_tracking.html#using-history-user-to-record-which-user-changed-a-model)

**models.py**

```
class UserTrackMixin(models.Model):

    changed_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    @property
    def _history_user(self):
        return self.changed_by

    @_history_user.setter
    def _history_user(self, value):
        self.changed_by = value

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Service(BaseModel, UserTrackMixin):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    serviceType = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

But, when i am trying to assign user object to the attribute `_history_user` to service object it gives error as mentioned below.

```
u1=User.objects.first()
<User: User object (07ab8565-26c7-4bfa-a92e-e12bf924160a)>
s._history_user = u1
s.save()

ValueError: Cannot assign "<User: User object (07ab8565-26c7-4bfa-a92e-e12bf924160a)>": "HistoricalService.history_user" must be a "User" instance.
```

Then i tried this :

```
s.changed_by = u1
s.save()
```

This also gave the same error.

**`u1` is User instance, then why does it give this error ?**

Answer (score 1):

`_history_user` is used by `django-simple-history` internally, you don't have to call it (hence the _ as prefix of the function)

Use `changed_by` instead:

```
u1 = User.objects.first()
s.changed_by = u1
s.save()
```

Comment: i tried this first, gives the same error.





`s.changed_by=u1
s.save()
ValueError: Cannot assign "<User: User object (07ab8565-26c7-4bfa-a92e-e12bf924160a)>": "HistoricalService.history_user" must be a "User" instance.
`

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with my code.

I didn't have the variable `AUTH_USER_MODEL` defined in the settings file due to which history assumes `'auth.User'` as the default user as can be seen here which is not the user model i am using as i have defined my custom user model.

So, i need to explicitly mention the user model i am using for user tracking.

Final code:

```
    @property
    def _history_user(self):
        return self.changed_by

    @_history_user.setter
    def _history_user(self, value):
        self.changed_by = value

    history = HistoricalRecords(user_model=User)
```